# Weak interaction and charge conjugation $C$

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction, charge-conjugation

Does the weak interaction always change the charge of all participating particles?

And in this context, what does $C$-violation do then?

Comment: Don't forget about the interactions including the neutral Z boson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The always charge-conserving weak interaction most often changes species of particles; it doesn't  change their charge.

Consider the iconic charged current weak reaction, 
$$
  \to e_L ~\bar \nu_{eR} ~\nu_{\mu L} ~, 
$$
while the C-symmetric reaction with the same chiralities is *not* the actual decay that goes,
$$
 \bar \mu \to e^+_R ~\nu_{eL} ~\bar \nu_{\mu R} ~. 
$$

So the weak interaction violates *C* maximally, since the first reaction has a left-chiral electron,  whereas the second reaction  has the positron be right handed. So the second reaction that actually goes requires a *P* operation to be applied at the same time to yield the *C*-conjugate of the first one. Then *CP*  is (mostly) conserved, while both *C* and *P* are violated maximally.

So *C* and *P* are not  good symmetries of these weak decays, but *CP* mostly is.

Comment: Thank you! So when I wanna' consider any c-violation I have to have a look at two reactions, not only on one (just to make it clear for me)? Means I look that both reactions are possible (in this case myon and anti-myon) and when I see both are possible it is not c-violating?

Comment: btw, how do I know that the lower reaction is not possible?

Comment: @Ben, the lower reaction *is* the one that goes, so it is possible! (with R $e^+$, etc...). But  is the C-conjugate reaction of the upper one: that one would require  an L $e^+$ which does not couple to the W, so this one, the C-conjugate, does not go. I prefer to not write reactions that don't go, as they stick in the mind... Whereas there is no harm in recalling reactions that *do* go. M Schwartz's book on the SM summarizes these rules quite nicely. Indeed, if a reaction and its C-conjugate go, C is preserved--not violated.

Comment: Hello professor, I have questions about your first expression, could you please check my post?https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/736490/chirality-in-muon-decay

Comment: Apologies, I am using the symbols to indicate states, and not the fields that destroy them.  The L,R subscripts I use indicate the actual chirality of the state, contrary to common practice. The field that destroys a right-handed antineutrino, above, is actually $\overline{ \nu_L}= \bar \nu P_R$.

Answer (score 1):

Weak interaction vertices involving a charged $W^+$ or $W^-$ boson change the charge of the quark or lepton by $\pm 1$. Weak interaction vertices involving a neutral $Z$ boson do not change the charge. The point is that charge is conserved, but not all of the weak bosons carry charge.