# How is C-symmetry violated?

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry, weak-interaction, charge-conjugation

I see how P-symmetry and CP-symmetry are  violated, but no one is talking about experiments related to C-symmetry. How did people prove that C-symmetry is  violated?

Comment: C has been [shown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_parity#Experimental_tests_of_C-parity_conservation) to hold for strong and electromagnetic interactions, but is (maximally) violated for the weak interactions, essentially baked into the structure of the standard model.  Many many many (most) weak decays violate C.

Comment: Near [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/496513/66086).